# How to access system permissions REMOVE_TASKS?

Tags: android, security, exception, permissions

I'm designing an application for removing recents tasks. Because of the need to access system permissions like `REMOVE_TASKS`

and i got this in my **log**

> **Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: removeTask() from pid=12579, uid=10066 requires
>   android.permission.REMOVE_TASKS**

I am using this code:

```
public boolean removeTask(int taskId, int flags) {
    try {
        return (Boolean) mRemoveTask.invoke(mActivityManager, Integer.valueOf(taskId), Integer.valueOf(flags) );
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.i("MyActivityManager", "Task removal failed", ex);
    }
    return false;
}

public void clearRecentTasks() {
    List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recents = mActivityManager.getRecentTasks(1000, ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE);
    // Start from 1, since we don't want to kill ourselves!
    for( int i=1; i < recents.size(); i++ ) {
        removeTask( recents.get(i).persistentId, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MikeM. my manifest don't have any duplicate permission of this type of permission. So please suggestion more answer regarding this.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, but Shahid Khan seems to want to answer your questions. Ask them.

Comment: @MikeM. Ok thank you